# Physical port protection

Tags: port, physical-security

I`m trying to find resources about Side Electromagnetic Radiation of computer ports, data bus, or any other channel, which can carry valuable information, and how it is possible to sniff this information, and then protect ports. What vulnerability exists, maybe some classification, methods of protection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by Googling "tempest attacks"

The canonical TEMPEST attack is to pick up the EM radiation from the CRT as it paints the picture so that the eavesdropper can recreate what's on the screen of the computer being watched.

"tempest attacks neal stephenson" will get some other links that might be more general since he used it in the book Cryptonomicon.

Comment: He referred to it in the novel as "Van Eck Phreaking" which is another common term for this technique. Comes from Wim van Eck who published the first paper, and proof of concept.

Comment: Well, I have found what I was looking for. That is it electromagnetic emanations http://lasecwww.epfl.ch/keyboard/

Answer (score 1):

You could talk to [Victor Munoz](http://events.ccc.de/congress/2007/Fahrplan/speakers/1752.en.html), who had an interesting talk about [AES side channel attacks](http://events.ccc.de/congress/2007/Fahrplan/events/2324.en.html) in 2007. I believe he could give you some interesting pointers.